# Get particular user by his JobTitle : REST Api

Tags: 2013, workflow, rest, designer-workflow

I want to get particular user's email by his Job title.
Basically, I need to send email to person with Job title of exp. IT support.

I thought I should start with this command:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='SPS-JobTitle')?@v='domain\username'
```

It gets job title of particular user.
So I need a reverse thing. To get particular user based on job title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to use the search query:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='JobTitle:IT support'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'
```

Here, JobTitle is a managed property. Usually its exists in the 2013 Search schema, but if its not present, create a custom managed property and map it to `People:SPS-JobTitle, ows_JobTitle` and then use that property in the query text.

Here, source id parameter is used for people scoped results.

Comment: Thanks for post. When I enter this in my workflow I receive error in email, same message as if I didn't put this command in AppStep. part of message: ..Access denied. You do not have permission.. Any help?

Comment: Even tried this command too, http://server/_api/search/query?query_parameter=value. Also same error. Text of error is same as if I would forgot to put SharePoint Add-ins xml code.

Comment: Try hitting the url in browser/postman json client. If it works there, some permission might be missing for workflow. I think you need read permission of user profile and search, if using in workflow. Personally, have used in webpart code and it works, so no reason it shouldn't in workflow.

Comment: It works in browser :) But I still cannot find solution to give workflow permissions for search. Any help? I know it's additional question, but still it's tied with main topic :)

Comment: You mentioned that you are using AppStep. So, in the AppStep permission should look something as below:

`<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="Write" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/search" Right="QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>`

am not an expert in workflows but referred this link :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx

Comment: solved. problem was I put that command in App step. As soon as I moved it out of app step it worked. Thanks!